# How to retrieve oracle Timestamp column in expected timezone in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, datetime

I have a timestamp column in oracle table. While storing time I store it in UTC in this column. For retrieving this time stamp I am using Spring's JdbcTemplate while returns object of type TimeStamp.

I want to get date time string in "dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss" format in current time zone. In order to achieve that I am trying following code:

```
new LocalDateTime(<retrieved TimeStamp>, <current user DateTimeZone>).toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Both LocalDateTime and DateTimeZone from Joda library.

How ever this isn't working as per expected. Instead of current user's time zone above code gives me date time string in UTC only.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the fully qualified class name for the LocalDateTime you're instantiating here? I'm unable to find any documentation resembling what you're doing.

Comment: My bad. Updated in description. It's from Joda library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add utc calendar when fetching the timestamp from database, so the jdbc driver can use this calendar timezone instead of default system timezone.

```
//Assign utc calendar
Calendar utc= Calendar.getInstance();
utc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp("timestampcolumn", utc);
//Convert to client date time
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp.getTime(), DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
//Format
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
//Change to client wall clock time
LocalDateTime localDateTime = dateTime.toLocalDateTime();
String formattedlocalDateTime = formatter.print(localDateTime)
```

**Example**

```
String utcTime = "2016-06-17 14:22:02Z";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
DateTime dateTime = parser.parseDateTime(utcTime).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(dateTime);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = dateTime.toLocalDateTime();
String formattedlocalDateTime = formatter.print(localDateTime);
System.out.println(formattedlocalDateTime);
```

Comment: Is this approach giving you date time in correct time zone? I tried this and I am still having the issue.

Comment: Updated answer with example. You can input your values and see if it works for you,

Comment: For the same code I am getting following values on my machine: timestamp: 2016-06-17 09:33:25.0 ,datetime: 2016-06-17T09:33:25.000+05:30 ,localDateTime: 2016-06-17T09:33:25.000, formatter.print(localDateTime): 17-06-2016 09:33:25. I have used "Asia/Kolkata" as time zone.

Comment: Updated answer to include the utc calendar.

Comment: Passing utc calendar while retrieving timestamp solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think your application is using `java.util.Date` which has no time zone information, the `toString` usage applies the JVM’s current default time zone when creating a string.

You can adjust the timezone instant by ([Using Joda Library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/))

```
ZonedDateTime Tokyo = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant (instant,zoneIdTokyo) ;
```

Or implement zones

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Tokyo");
```

You are using 
`LocalDateTime` which is immutable class representing a **local date and time (no time zone)**

EDIT - You can try this 
(I haven't tested it)

```
DateTime udate = new DateTime("2016-05-01T20:10:04", DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(udate);
DateTime zone = udate.plusMillis(10000)
.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(zone);
```

Comment: I would be very thankful if you can provide small code snippet which actually transforms Timestamp object to formatted string.